# Vertical synchronized bar on multiple plots, following user cursor

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-app-designer

I'm trying to create an app for data analysis.
I have multiple channels of acquisition of the same length, including a time vector.
Vectors as therefore synchronized (same index value corrispond to the same time instant for every array).

I display data on different figures (UIAxes) in my app figure.
To better and more easily use the application I would like the following to happen: each time the user hovers the cursor on any plot a vertical bar at the corrisponding x position of the cursor is displayed, on all the figures. All the figures display the same range of x values.

I also have a scatter figure with points from gps, still with the same length of the other arrays.
On that figure I'd really like to have, instead of the vertical line, a crosshair.

I've found this part of code here but I can't adapt it to App Designer and it's also pretty old.

Any kind of help is very welcome.

EDIT: Matlab Version 2020b

Comment: This question is currently a bit broad, can you perhaps limit it to a specific part of this task, i.e. getting the cursor position from an axes object in app designer if that's the core of the issue? Since app designer is a new(ish) feature of MATLAB and it evolved relatively quickly it would also be helpful to include which version of MATLAB you're using

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I will try to limit the question, I take just a bit of time to identify the hardest point of it. I will also immediately add the version.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.